# Use indexOf to detect if the value has comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events, indexof

I'm trying to use the `indexOf` property in JavaScript/jQuery to detect if there's a comma in a value. This is what I'm trying:

```
var valueTotalCost = data.TotalCost;
                            if (valueTotalCost.indexOf('.') > -1)
                            { $('table#cartTable tr#' + data.AppItemId + ' td:nth-child(3)').text('£' + data.TotalCost); }
                            else
                            { $('table#cartTable tr#' + data.AppItemId + ' td:nth-child(3)').text('£' + data.TotalCost + '.00'); }
```

I'm getting an error

> valueTotalCost.indexOf is not a function

What might I be doing wrong and how I can fix this? I want to detect if the value already has decimals then don't  put tow trailing decimal places, otherwise put two decimal places.

Comment: What does data.TotalCost look like normally?

Comment: Post the whole script.

Comment: It looks like your value isn't a string. If it's a number the check is completely different.

Comment: Is `valueTotalCost` a number? Do `console.log(typeof valueTotalCost)` to find out. `indexOf` only works on strings or arrays.

Comment: Run `alert(typeof valueTotalCost)` and post the result. And specify which browser you are using.

Comment: check a number has a decimal part : `valueTotalCost!==Math.floor(valueTotalCost)`

Comment: @dystroy - They're looking to remove commas, not decimals.

Comment: @MikeChristensen That's not what I infer from `valueTotalCost.indexOf('.') `.

Comment: @MikeChristensen brings up a valid point. You're asking to identify comma's but your code targets decimals. Which is it?

Comment: @dystroy - You're right.  Now I'm confused.

Comment: @MikeChristensen In some countries the decimal separator is the comma. Which makes people in these countries prone to use "comma" when they really mean "dot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first line from

```
var valueTotalCost = data.TotalCost;
```

to

```
var valueTotalCost = data.TotalCost.toString();
```

The reason that you're having this problem is most likely because you are trying to use `.indexOf()` on a number of some kind. `.indexOf()` is a string method, and so it isn't accessible on numbers.

Usually when you run into a problem like this, I would recommend hopping on Google and searching for the method name. Then you can hit up a Mozilla Resource (generally the easiest to read in my opinion.) like this one:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: Or just `data.TotalCost + ''`

Comment: @Oriol You could definitely do that. I usually prefer toString() just because it makes it easier to understand what's happening to a casual observer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var valueTotalCost = String(data.TotalCost);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: FYI, [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) is the link to the `String()` function on the _Mozilla Developer Network_. You'll probably get hammered with downvotes for using _w3schools_ as a reference...

Comment: Please don't link w3schools because of [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/) is much better.